# Ember-CLI Route model data not affecting template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, handlebars.js

I have an ember route `webtest` contained within the file `routes/webtest.js`:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return {
      title: "Does not appear"
    };
  }
});
```

I have the matching template contained within `templates/webtest.hbs`

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Title: {{title}}</h2>
</div>
```

when I navigate to the page /webtest in my web browser with `ember serve`
the resulting page has the `title:` text, but not the text `does not appear`

I have been to multiple ember pages, and I have the same code working here:
http://jsbin.com/neheru/6/edit?html,js,output

The goal is to be able to have a variable accessible from within the template `webtest` that can be accessed by a route.

FYI I'm trying to get it to the template so I can pass variables to a component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable should be {{model.title}}

You can log out variables from your template with

```
{{log title}}
{{log controller.title}}
{{log model.title}}
```

This might help you to debug faster.

You should then be able to pass data in to our component with something like:

```
{{my-component title=model.title}}
```

Comment: We've all been there. I got stung by this a few times